# How do I get this expression Chr$(&H8) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How do I get this expression Chr$(&H8) in Javascript. I need to get this escape code in Javascript

```
sCmd = Chr$(&H8) + Chr$(&H2)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try String.fromCharCode(), or you can use these escape sequences:

```
\ddd      Octal sequence (3 digits: ddd)
\xdd      Hexadecimal sequence (2 digits: dd)
\udddd    Unicode sequence (4 hex digits: dddd)
```

Comment: with "fromCharCode" works this way "String.fromCharCode("0xdd","0xd1") ", But how could I express "0x08" "0x01" or "\x08" "\x01"?

Answer (score 2):

```
sCmd = String.fromCharCode("&#0xh8") + String.fromCharCode("&#0xh2")
```